# Any Solution for Hosting native Window views with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, desktop, win32gui, flutter-desktop

My company is planning to make a "Camera Application" on **Windows platform**.
To display camera livestream on the app, I need to call native **3rd SDK' functions** that be **written by C++**.
So I need to pass **HWND(int)** of the views that I want as a argument of SDK' function to perform action livestream

The question is "**How do I get HWND of Flutter Widget**" or "**How do I host a native Window as a Widget**"

Comment: had similar requirement here

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open issue for this [#31713](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31713). You can try [flutter_native_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_view) if that works for you